# Print an empty dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Twitter api, but some tweets return empty, like hashtags. How can I print it? Or at least, a message that it is empty.

This is what I have so far:

```
def get_tweets(q, count=100, result_type="recent"):
    result = search_tweets(q, count, result_type)
    following = set(t.friends.ids(screen_name=TWITTER_HANDLE)["ids"])
    for tweet in result['statuses']:
        try:
            print tweet
            print tweet['text']
            print str(tweet['user']['id'])
            print tweet['hashtags']
            #print 'user mentions ' + tweet['users_mentions'] + tweet['hashtags']
            time.sleep(30) # Sleep for 1 hour
        except TwitterHTTPError as e:
            print "error: ", e
            if "blocked" not in str(e).lower():
                quit()
```

But I'm getting an error on

```
print tweet['hashtags']
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in get_tweets
KeyError: 'hashtags'
```

Comment: `if 'hashtags' in tweet: print tweet['hashtags']`

Comment: `time.sleep(30)` - this doesn't sleep for an hour, but 30 seconds.

Comment: "Or at least, a message that it is empty." - @karolyhorvath read the question first, then do comments

Comment: @burhankhalid thanks for the help. I know this, but when I was testing  i thought 1 hour was a long time to wait haha

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what or means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**dict.get()**

You want to use the get() function.

From the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

`get(key[, default]):
    Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. 
    If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method 
    never raises a KeyError.`

**An Example**

```
In [2]: foo = {'a': 1}

In [3]: foo['b']
...
KeyError: 'b'

In [4]: foo.get('b', "B not found")
Out[4]: 'B not found'
```

**Check membership in keys**

As an alternative, you can check if the key exists, and conditionally report an error.

```
if 'hashtags' in tweet.keys():
    #do stuff if the hashtag exists
else:
    #do error condition
```

You can choose whichever is most appropriate for your situation.

**Your code**

Here's what your code might look like with those changes.

```
def get_tweets(q, count=100, result_type="recent"):
    ...
    for tweet in result['statuses']:
        ...
        print tweet.get('hashtags', "")
        if 'user_mentions' in tweet.keys():
            print 'user mentions ' + 
                tweet.get['users_mentions'] +  
                tweet.get('hashtags', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

As already answered, you can use the [`dict.get()`](http://devdocs.io/python/library/stdtypes#dict.get) call to search. Otherwise, you can use the following `if-else` block:

```
if 'hashtags' in tweet:
    print tweet['hashtags']
else:
    print "No hashtags"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `get` method, the first argument is the key, the second is the value to return if the key doesn't exist:

```
print tweet.get('hashtags', None)
```